# Remove Whitespaces From Database Column

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have to update a column to the same values but without whitespaces.

I tried following but getting error

```
update CERT_REQUEST set CERT_REQUEST_nbr = Trim(cert_request_nbr)
```

I am getting followig error

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-668, SQLSTATE=57016, SQLERRMC=7;DB2ADMIN.CERT_REQUEST, DRIVER=3.50.152
SQLState:  57016
ErrorCode: -668
```

I am using DB2 database, 9.07 version

Comment: What error are you getting?  Why is a column with the suffix "nbr" being stored as a string?

Comment: Which errors? Note that trim only removes leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it's an already existing databse, So I don't know the reason why, but I have to remove the whitespaces

Answer (score 3):

The [error message](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00668n.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-6-27-1-103) indicates that the table `DB2ADMIN.CERT_REQUEST` is in a `REORG PENDING` state. You (or your DBA) will need to run a `REORG` on the table before it can be updated.

> ### SQL0668N
>
> Operation not allowed for reason code *reason-code* on table
>   *table-name*.
>
> **Explanation**
>
> **7**
>
> The table is in the reorg pending state. This can occur after an ALTER
>   TABLE statement containing a REORG-recommended operation.
>
> **User response**
>
> **7**
>
> Reorganize the table using the REORG TABLE command.
>
> For a table in the reorg pending state, note that the following clauses are not allowed when reorganizing the table:
>
> - The INPLACE REORG TABLE clause
> - The ON DATA PARTITION clause for a partitioned table when table has nonpartitioned indexes defined on the table

You can get all of this information from the error message. The `-668` SQLCODE translates to the `SQL0668N` entry in Info Center, and the `SQLERRMC` field shows which sub-code (and table) caused the error.